# How do you make a Trello board "read only" to people without making the board completely public

Tags: trello

I have a scenario where I would like **one** person (a Trello user) to be able to view a board and read the cards but not comment, vote or move cards.

I currently have the board belonging to an organisation. My "public user" is a member of the board but not the organisation. As such he can comment, vote and move cards.

It appears that if I make the board publicly viewable and remove my "public user" from the board, I could achieve what I want by setting the permissions for commenting and voting to "Organization Members" or "Member" but I can't find a way to have only **selected Trello users** view the board without allowing them to edit it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I found to do this, is by changing the Board permissions so that only members can make changes to the Board. People in the Organization can view the board, but they can't become members unless invited to the board.

This way I can invite people to the Organization, let them view the board, and still, they will not be authorized to change anything on the board, and can't join the board without my specific action.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible now, but we have an open feature request to offer **Anyone with the URL**--level accessibility. The functionality provides value and is well-understood from other web applications.

Please email us at **feature-ideas@trello.com** to express your support for this feature.

When it gets enough traction, we'll move it to https://trello.com/dev

Comment: 10 years later, and this is still not possible.

I'm trying to figure out a way of putting the Trello board onto the wall monitor in our office. We're using software called Airtame, and a lot of software has a view-only link with a secret token in the URL, that only admins can create. Something like that would be great for Trello!